# How to remove element tags from results, Web Scraping Articles with Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I've recently been teaching myself python and instead of diving right into courses I decided to think of some script ideas I could research and work through myself. The first I decided to make after seeing something similar referenced in a video was a web scraper to grab articles from sites, such as the New York Times. (I'd like to preface the post by stating that I understand some sites might have varying TOS regarding this and I want to make it clear I'm only doing this to learn the aspects of code and do not have any other motive -- I also *have* an account to NYT and have not done this on websites where I do not possess an account)

I've gained a bit of an understanding of the python required to perform this as well as began utilizing some BeautifulSoup commands and some of it works well! I've found the specific elements that refer to parts of the article in F12 inspect and am able to successfully grab just the text from these parts.

When it comes to the body of the article, however, the elements are set up in such a way that I'm having troubling grabbing all of the text and not bringing some tags along with it.

Where I'm at so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/2022/01/08/us/teachers-unions-covid-schools.html').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print('----------')
print(f'TITLE: {soup.title.string}')
print('----------')
print(f'H1: {soup.h1.string}')
print(f'H2: {soup.h2.string}')
print(f'H3: {soup.h3.string}')
print('----------')
article_summary = soup.find('p', class_='css-w6ymp8 e1wiw3jv0').text
print(f'Article summary: {article_summary}')
print('----------')
image_summary = soup.find('span', class_='css-16f3y1r e13ogyst0').text
print(f'Image summary: {image_summary}')
print('----------')
authors = soup.find('p', class_= 'css-aknsld e1jsehar1')
author1 = authors.find('span', class_= 'css-1baulvz').text
author2 = authors.find('span', class_= 'css-1baulvz last-byline').text
print(f'Authors: {author1} and {author2}')
print('----------')

for item in soup.select('.StoryBodyCompanionColumn'):
    try:
        para = item.find_all('p')
        print(para)
    except Exception as e:
        print('f')
```

The output I get from this is:

```
----------
TITLE: Teachers’ Unions Push for Remote Schooling, Worrying  Democrats - The New York Times
----------
H1: As More Teachers’ Unions Push for Remote Schooling, Parents Worry. So Do Democrats.
H2: The Coronavirus Pandemic: Latest Updates
H3: None
----------
Article summary: Chicago teachers have voted to go remote. Other unions are agitating for change. For Democrats, who promised to keep schools open, the tensions are a distinctly unwelcome development.
----------
Image summary: Alex Brandenburg, an elementary school teacher, protested outside of the Oakland Unified School District headquarters on Friday as part of a sick out.
----------
Authors: Dana Goldstein and Noam Scheiber
----------
[<p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Few American cities have labor politics as fraught as Chicago’s, where the nation’s third-largest school system shut down this week after teachers’ union members refused to work in person, arguing that classrooms were unsafe amid the Omicron surge.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">But in a number of other places, the tenuous labor peace that has allowed most schools to operate normally this year is in danger of collapsing.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">While not yet threatening to walk off the job, unions are back at negotiating tables, pushing in some cases for a return to remote learning. They frequently cite understaffing because of illness, and shortages of rapid tests and medical-grade masks. Some teachers, in a rear-guard action, have staged sick outs.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">In Milwaukee, schools are remote until Jan. 18, because of staffing issues. But the teachers’ union president, Amy Mizialko, doubts that the situation will significantly improve<span class="css-8l6xbc evw5hdy0"> </span>and worries that the school board will resist extending online classes.</p>]
[<p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">“I anticipate it’ll be a fight,” Ms. Mizialko said.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">She credited the district for at least delaying in-person schooling to start the year but criticized Democratic officials for placing unrealistic pressure on teachers and schools.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">“I think that Joe Biden and Miguel Cardona and the newly elected mayor of New York City and Lori Lightfoot — they can all declare that schools will be open,” Ms. Mizialko added, referring to the U.S. education secretary and the mayor of Chicago. “But unless they have hundreds of thousands of people to step in for educators who are sick in this uncontrolled surge, they won’t be.”</p>]
[<p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">For many parents and teachers, the pandemic has become a slog of anxiety over the risk of infection, child care crises, the tedium of school-through-a-screen and, most of all, chronic instability.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">And for Democrats, the revival of tensions over remote schooling is a distinctly unwelcome development.</p>]
[<p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Because they have close ties to the unions, Democrats are concerned that additional closures like those in Chicago could lead to a possible replay of the party’s recent loss in Virginia’s governor race. <a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://dfer.org/press/poll-confirms-education-motivating-issue-for-va-voters-in-2021-election-likely-to-be-major-factor-in-midterms/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" title="">Polling</a> showed that school disruptions were an important issue for swing voters who broke Republican — particularly suburban white women.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">“It’s a big deal in most state polling we do,” said Brian Stryker, a partner at the polling firm ALG Research <a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://thirdway.imgix.net/pdfs/override/Qualitative-Research-Findings-%E2%80%93-Virginia-Post-Election-Research.pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" title="">whose work</a> in Virginia indicated that school closures hurt Democrats.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">“Anyone who thinks this is a political problem that stops at the Chicago city line is kidding themselves,” added Mr. Stryker, whose firm polled for President Biden’s 2020 campaign. “This is going to resonate all across Illinois, across the country.”</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">More than one million of the country’s 50 million public school students<span class="css-8l6xbc evw5hdy0"> </span>were affected by districtwide shutdowns in the first week of January, many of which were announced abruptly and triggered a wave of frustration among parents.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">“The kids are not the ones that are seriously ill by and large, but we know kids are the ones suffering from remote learning,” said Dan Kirk, whose son attends Walter Payton College Preparatory High School in Chicago, which was closed amid the district’s standoff this week.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Several nonunion charter-school networks and districts temporarily transitioned to remote learning after the holidays. But as has been true throughout the pandemic, most of the temporary districtwide closures — including in Detroit, Cleveland, Milwaukee — are taking place in liberal-leaning areas with powerful unions and a more cautious approach to the coronavirus.</p>]
[<p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">The unions’ demands echo the ones they have made for nearly two years, despite all that has changed. There are now vaccines and <a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/science/science-briefs/transmission_k_12_schools.html#sars-cov-2" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" title="">the reassuring knowledge</a> that in-school transmission of the virus has been limited.<span class="css-8l6xbc evw5hdy0"> </span>The Omicron variant, while highly contagious, appears to cause less severe illness than previous iterations of Covid-19. </p>]
[<p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Most district leaders and many educators say it is imperative for schools to remain open. They cite a large body of research showing that closures harm children, <a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://www.nytimes.com/2021/07/28/us/covid-schools-at-home-learning-study.html" title="">academically</a> and <a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://www.nytimes.com/2022/01/04/briefing/american-children-crisis-pandemic.html" title="">emotionally</a>, and widen income and racial disparities. </p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">But some local union officials are far warier of packed classrooms. In Newark, schools began 2022 with an unexpected stretch of remote learning, set to end on Jan. 18. John Abeigon, the Newark Teachers Union president, said he was hopeful about the return to buildings but that he remained unsure if every school could operate safely.<span class="css-8l6xbc evw5hdy0"> </span>Student vaccination is far from universal, and most parents have not consented to their children taking regular virus tests.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Mr. Abeigon said that if tests remain scarce, he might ask for remote learning at specific schools with low vaccination rates and high case counts. He agreed that online learning was a burden to working parents but argued that educators should not be sacrificed for the good of the economy.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">“I’d see the entire city of Newark unemployed before I allowed one single teacher’s aide to die needlessly,” he said.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">In Los Angeles, the district has worked closely with the union to keep classrooms open after one of the longest pandemic shutdowns in the country last school year. The vaccination rate for students 12 and older is about 90 percent, with a student vaccine mandate set to <a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://www.nytimes.com/2021/12/18/us/los-angeles-vaccine-mandate-delayed.html" title="">kick in this fall</a>. All students and staff are tested for the virus weekly.</p>]
[<p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Still, the president of the local union, Cecily Myart-Cruz, would not rule out pushing for a districtwide return to remote learning in the coming weeks. “You know, I want to be honest — I don’t know,” she said.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">The tensions are not limited to liberal<span class="css-8l6xbc evw5hdy0"> </span>states. In Kentucky, teachers’ unions and at least <a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://www.wdrb.com/in-depth/remote-learning-probable-at-some-point-for-jcps-as-covid-19-cases-surge-pollio-says/article_aae24c48-6e40-11ec-846b-5bdbd3d76870.html" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" title="">one large school district</a> have said they need the flexibility to go remote amid escalating infection rates.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">But the Republican-controlled state legislature has granted no more than 10 days for such instruction districtwide, and unions there worry that may be inadequate. Jeni Ward Bolander, a leader of a statewide union, said that teachers may have to walk off the job.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">“Frustration is building on teachers,” Ms. Ward Bolander said. “I hate to say we’d walk out at that point, but it’s absolutely possible.”</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">National teachers’ unions continue to call for classrooms to remain open, but local affiliates hold the most power in negotiations over whether individual districts will close schools.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">And over the last decade, some locals, including those in Los Angeles and Chicago, were taken over by activist leaders whose tactics can be more aggressive than those of national leaders like <a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://www.nytimes.com/2021/02/08/us/schools-reopening-teachers-unions.html" title="">Randi Weingarten</a> of the American Federation of Teachers and <a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://www.nytimes.com/2021/12/12/us/politics/teachers-union-becky-pringle.html" title="">Becky Pringle</a> of the National Education Association, both close allies of President Biden.</p>]
[<p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Complicating matters, some local unions face internal pressure from their own members. <a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://sanfrancisco.cbslocal.com/2022/01/06/covid-oakland-unified-school-district-warns-potential-teacher-sickout/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" title="">In the Bay Area</a>, splinter groups of teachers in both Oakland and San Francisco have planned sick outs, and demanded N95 masks, more virus testing and other safety measures.</p>, <p class="itemClass"><strong>The latest Covid data in the U.S.<!-- --> </strong><span>As the Omicron surge causes case counts to reach record highs and hospitalizations to surpass the height of the Delta wave, here’s <a href="https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2022/01/07/us/covid-data-explained.html?action=click&amp;pgtype=Article&amp;state=default&amp;module=styln-coronavirus&amp;variant=show&amp;region=MAIN_CONTENT_3&amp;block=storyline_levelup_swipe_recirc">how to think about the data</a> and what it’s beginning to show about <a href="https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2022/01/09/us/omicron-cities-cases-hospitals.html?action=click&amp;pgtype=Article&amp;state=default&amp;module=styln-coronavirus&amp;variant=show&amp;region=MAIN_CONTENT_3&amp;block=storyline_levelup_swipe_recirc">Omicron’s potential toll across the county</a>.</span></p>, <p class="itemClass"><strong>Around the world.<!-- --> </strong><span>In Europe, <a href="https://www.nytimes.com/live/2022/01/10/world/omicron-covid-testing-vaccines/germany-braces-for-more-protests-as-vaccine-rules-tighten-across-europe?action=click&amp;pgtype=Article&amp;state=default&amp;module=styln-coronavirus&amp;variant=show&amp;region=MAIN_CONTENT_3&amp;block=storyline_levelup_swipe_recirc">Germany is bracing for major protests</a> against restrictions after thousands took to the streets in France and Austria, and a tough new vaccine requirement came into force in Italy. In Uganda, <a href="https://www.nytimes.com/2022/01/10/world/africa/uganda-schools-reopen.html?action=click&amp;pgtype=Article&amp;state=default&amp;module=styln-coronavirus&amp;variant=show&amp;region=MAIN_CONTENT_3&amp;block=storyline_levelup_swipe_recirc">schools reopened</a> after the longest pandemic-prompted shutdown in the world.</span></p>, <p class="itemClass"><strong>Staying safe.<!-- --> </strong><span>Worried about spreading Covid? Keep yourself and others safe by following some basic guidance on <a href="https://www.nytimes.com/article/tests-covid-omicron-pcr-rapid.html?action=click&amp;pgtype=Article&amp;state=default&amp;module=styln-coronavirus&amp;variant=show&amp;region=MAIN_CONTENT_3&amp;block=storyline_levelup_swipe_recirc">when to test</a> and <a href="https://www.nytimes.com/article/at-home-covid-tests-accuracy.html?action=click&amp;pgtype=Article&amp;state=default&amp;module=styln-coronavirus&amp;variant=show&amp;region=MAIN_CONTENT_3&amp;block=storyline_levelup_swipe_recirc">how to use at-home virus tests</a> (if you can find them). Here is what to do <a href="https://www.nytimes.com/article/testing-positive-covid-omicron-variant.html?action=click&amp;pgtype=Article&amp;state=default&amp;module=styln-coronavirus&amp;variant=show&amp;region=MAIN_CONTENT_3&amp;block=storyline_levelup_swipe_recirc">if you test positive for the coronavirus</a>.</span></p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Rori Abernethy, a middle-school teacher in San Francisco, organized a sick out there on Thursday. She said the Chicago action had prompted some teachers to ask, “Why isn’t our union doing this?”</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">In Chicago and San Francisco, working-class parents of color disproportionately send their children to the public schools, and they have often supported strict safety measures during the pandemic, including periods of remote learning. And in New York, the nation’s largest school district, schools are operating in person with increased virus testing, with limited dissent from teachers.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">But the politics become more complicated in suburbs, where union leaders may find themselves at odds with public officials at pains to<span class="css-8l6xbc evw5hdy0"> </span>preserve in-person schooling.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">In Fairfax County, Virginia’s largest district, the superintendent has <a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://www.fcps.edu/return-school/return-school-safety/navigating-january-2022-covid-surge" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" title="">a plan</a> for switching individual schools to remote learning in the event of many absent teachers.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Kimberly Adams, the president of the<span class="css-8l6xbc evw5hdy0"> </span>local education association, said her union may want stricter measures. And she said that districts should be planning for virus surges by distributing devices for potential short bursts of online schooling. </p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">But Dan Helmer, a Democratic state delegate whose swing district includes part of Fairfax County, said there was little support among his constituents for a return to online education.</p>]
[<p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Deb Andraca, a Democratic state representative in Wisconsin whose district lies just north of Milwaukee, where schools went remote this past week, said that Republicans have targeted her seat and that she expected schools to be a line of attack.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">“Everyone I know wants schools to stay open,” she said. “But there’s a lot of talk about how teachers’ unions don’t want schools to stay open.”</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Jim Hobart, a partner at Public Opinion Strategies, a polling firm that counts several Republican senators and governors as clients, said the school closure issue created two advantages for G.O.P. candidates. It has helped narrow their margins among a demographic they’ve traditionally struggled with — white women between their mid-20s and mid-50s — and it has generally undermined Democrats’ claims to competence.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">“A lot of people — Biden, Mayor Lightfoot in Chicago — have said schools should be open,” Mr. Hobart said. “If they’re not able to prevent schools from choosing to close, that shows a weakness on their part.”</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Labor officials say that many of their critics are acting in bad faith, exploiting parents’ pandemic-related frustrations to advance longstanding political goals, like discrediting unions and expanding private-school vouchers.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">Thus far, neither the critiques nor the broader pandemic challenges appear to have significantly hampered unions’ public standing, even according to <a class="css-1g7m0tk" href="https://www.educationnext.org/hunger-for-stability-quells-appetite-for-change-results-2021-education-next-survey-public-opinion-poll/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" title="">polls</a> conducted by<span class="css-8l6xbc evw5hdy0"> </span>researchers skeptical of teachers’ unions.</p>]
[<p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">And if it turns out that Democratic candidates pay a political price for unions’ assertiveness, local labor officials do not consider it to be among their top concerns.</p>, <p class="css-axufdj evys1bk0">If periods of remote learning this winter hurt the Democratic Party, “that’s a question for the consultants and the brain trusts to figure out,” said Mr. Abeigon, the Newark union president. “But that it’s the right thing to do? There’s no question in my mind.”</p>, <p class="css-pncxxs etfikam0">Holly Secon<!-- --> contributed reporting from San Francisco.</p>]
```

I feel so close to having it accomplished, but I've hit a roadblock so I'm hoping someone can tell me how to clean this up a bit.

If I were to do:

```
for item in soup.select('.StoryBodyCompanionColumn'):
    try:
        para = item.find('p').text
        print(para)
    except Exception as e:
        print('f')
```

If I use find('p').text or find('p').get_text instead of find_all('p'), it will either give me a failure and print out f or it will give me only the FIRST paragraph within a certain div.*(I can upload the results that it spits out when I do the other options but there's a few more I could add and it would greatly lengthen this post even further)* (This article has 10 or 11 different divs for the body, each with 2-4 paragraphs in each, and they **ALL** possess the same class_= tag. **This is really where I've been running into an issue. I might be able to splice out the tags with some nifty coding that simply deletes the undesired tags from my results, but I'd rather have smoother code that actually works and I know I'm missing something. Any and all help is very much appreciated as I continue learning!**

(Apologies for length of post or if it's an inadequate question -- I'm knew to the site & programming overall so I'm at the stage where I don't know what I don't know yet, so if there is a link that answers my question instead of you taking time to respond that would be fantastic as well, thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the paragraphs more specific, while adding `p` to your `css selector`, than item is the paragraph and you can simply call `.text` or if there is something to strip -> `.text.strip()` or `.get_text(strip=True)`:

```
for item in soup.select('.StoryBodyCompanionColumn p'):
try:
    para = item.text
    print(para)
except Exception as e:
    print('f')
```

---

Just select the section tag that holds all p tags and call `get_text()` to get all human readable text:

```
soup.select_one('section[name="articleBody"]').get_text(strip=True)
```

or iterate over the divs and `join()` the texts to a single string:

```
' '.join([item.get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.select('.StoryBodyCompanionColumn p')])
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/2022/01/08/us/teachers-unions-covid-schools.html').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

soup.select_one('section[name="articleBody"]').get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: When I try it as I think you're suggesting I get this output:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/scraper/scraper3.py", line 27, in <module>
for item in soup.select('.StoryBodyCompanionColumn').get_text(strip=True):
File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/scraper/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 2253, in __getattr__ raise AttributeError(AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: If you wanna go with select instead of select_one you have to iterate over your result set `' '.join([item.get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.select('.StoryBodyCompanionColumn')])`

Comment: Thanks for the information HedgeHog. I am able to successfully get the full text without tags by using this method but instead of being formatted with line breaks and putting paragraphs on separate lines, it all comes out on one line in the console and places where breaks might be just meld together. This might look something like, "...end.Start" where there's no separation. Still not exactly what I'm looking for so I'm exploring more ways to accomplish this right now!

Comment: Edited the answer for the goal to print line by line - based on your example. Take a look.